# Count number of non-prime pairs that when multiplied form a given number N,

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, primes

A non-prime pair which forms N is 2 different non-prime numbers where the product of the numbers is N.

1<=N<=10^6

**For example** For N = 24 there are 2 good pairs (non-prime pairs that form N) (4,6), (1,24), but (2,12), (3,8) are not good.

**Note:** for any 2 numbers a and b pair(a,b) = pair(b,a).

There is another condition which states that if the number is a special number, so output = -1 otherwise count the number of non-primes.

**Number is called special number if it can be represented as a product of three prime numbers**. Example: 12 is a special number because 12=2*2*3;

I tried brute-force approach using **https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes** , 
which takes O(N*log(log(N)).

**"Is there any more optimized way to solve it except brute-force?"**

Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For these purpose mostly of time, the best solution is just compute the modulus. Prepare a vector of char with flags set if prime number, since sqrt(N). Than brute-force it with Modulus also since sqrt(N) and when you find a divisor, check if it is  prime.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: The wikipedia article you link to says “The sieve of Eratosthenes is one of the most efficient ways to find all of the smaller primes.” It also says that “the time complexity of calculating all primes below n in the random access machine model is O(n log⁡ log n) operations”. So if efficiency is your concern, I wouldn’t think you needed to do better to find the primes.

Comment: @OleV.V. thanks.very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Eratosthenes' sieve is O(N*log(log(N)) *to list all primes below or equal N* (when [well implemented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Algorithm_and_variants)).

Second: suppose you factored your number in `Q` primes with multiplicity which, without sieving, is a process of O(sqrt(N)) at worst (worst: your number is prime). So you have a map of:

- p<sub>0</sub> -> multiplicity m<sub>0</sub>
- p<sub>1</sub> -> multiplicity m<sub>1</sub>
- ...
- p<sub>Q</sub> -> multiplicity m<sub>Q</sub>

How many divisors made from multiplying at least 2 prime factors?

Well, there will be **`m0*m1*...mq`** of them [correction here]. Why? Well, prepare a list of all the divisors generated wit the powers of each factor (including p<sub>i</sub><sup>0</sup>==1), but cross out the ones with a power of `1`.

- {1, <strike>p<sub>0</sub></strike>, p<sub>0</sub><sup>2</sup>, ...p<sub>0</sub><sup>m0</sup>} are `m0` ways of generating divisors with the powers of `p0` except p0
- {1, <strike>p<sub>1</sub></strike>, p<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>, ...p<sub>1</sub><sup>m1</sup>} are `m1` ways of generating divisors with the powers of `p1` except p1
- ...
- {1, <strike>p<sub>Q</sub></strike>, p1<sup>Q</sup>, ...p1<sup>mQ</sup>} are `mQ` ways of generating divisors with the powers of `pQ`

The number of all combinations with non-prime divisors (as `1` is already included in each set and each prime factors by itself is excluded ) will be the cardinality of the cartesian product of all the above subsets - thus the product of the individual cardinalities, therefore `m0*m1*...mq`

---

Code - Java

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class Example {

  static void factor(long N, Map<Long, Short> primesWithMultiplicity) {
    // some arg checking and trivial cases
    if(N<0) N=-N;
    if(0==N) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException(
         "Are you kidding me? Every number divides 0, "+
         "you really want them all listed?"
       );
    }
    if(1==N) {
      primesWithMultiplicity.put(1L,(short)1);
      return;
    }

     // don't try divisors higher than sqrt(N), 
    // if they would have been detected by their composite-complement 
    for(long div=2; div*div < N; ) {
      short multiplicity=0;
      while((N % div)==0) {
        multiplicity++;
        N /= div; // reduce N
      }
      if(multiplicity>0) {
        primesWithMultiplicity.put(div, multiplicity);
      }
      div+= (div == 2 ? 1 : 2); // from 2 to 3, but then going only on odd numbers
    }
    // done.. well almost, if N is prime, then 
    // trying to divide up to sqrt(N) will lead an empty result. But,
    // in this case, N will still be at original value (as opposed 
    // to being 1 if complete factored)
    if(N>1) {
      primesWithMultiplicity.put(N, (short)1);
    }
  }

  static int countDistinctCompositePairs(long N) {
    HashMap<Long, Short> factoringResults=new HashMap<>();
    factor(N, factoringResults);
    int ret=1;
    for(short multiplicity : factoringResults.values()) {
      ret*=multiplicity;
    }
    return ret/2;
  }

  static public void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(countDistinctCompositePairs(24));
  }
}
```

Comment: @user5956891 Welcome (btw, thanks is usually expressed by upvoting the answer and/or accepting it if it really answers your question)

Comment: @user5956891 code corrected (I had some nasty bugs previously)

Comment: Sir code is giving result 6 instead of 2 when i am giving input N=24.

Comment: Colomithci Sir there is problem regarding incompatible types int can not be converted to Long.

Comment: "Sir code is giving result 6 instead of 2 when i am giving input N=24." Mmm... let me think a bit.

Comment: Sir I compiled code , still I got same result 6 instead of 2.

Comment: @user5956891 Copy/paste the entire code as it is now, it works on my computer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128535/discussion-between-user5956891-and-adrian-colomitchi).

Comment: Sir I did still same answer 6 instead of 2. when N=24.

Comment: @user5956891 apologies, the last correction - now it's all good. Teaches me alright to do SO at 3AM.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't mentioned the constraints I assume 1<=N<=10^6
Implement the sieve and simultaneously store the greatest prime factor of the numbers up to 10^6.

Here's the code for same.

```
int a[1000001];
a[1]=1;
for(int i=2;i*i<1000001;i++)
{
    if(a[i]==0)
    {
        for(int j=2*i;j<1000001;j+=i)
        a[j]=i;
    }
}
```

Now if the number is prime your answer is 0.

```
if(a[n]==0) 
cout<<'0';
```

If it is semi prime(product of two primes) your answer will be 1.

```
if(a[n/a[n]]==0)
cout<<"1";
```

If it is special then

```
int x=n/a[n];
if(a[x/a[x]]==0)
cout<<"-1";
```

If it doesn't satisfy any of the aforementioned conditions then calculate all non prime divisors.

```
int c=0;
for(int i=1;i*i<n;i++)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
        {
            if(a[i]!=0&&a[n/i]!=0)
            c++;

        }
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please try to fix it when N=12 then output = -1 but your code giving -11 instead of -1;

Comment: Actually problem is that when

Comment: Actually problem is that when

 `if(a[x/a[x]]==0)
{
cout<<"-1"<<endl;

}`
After that it should not calculate this code section

`int c=0;
for(int i=1;i*i<n;i++)
    {
        if(n%i==0)
        {
            if(a[i]!=0&&a[n/i]!=0)
            c++;

        }
    }
    cout<<c<<endl;`
that why it gives -11, -1 for special prime and second 1 because of calculation of Non-primes

Comment: @user5956891 actually I wrote the code snippets when you will code the problem use either if else or continue.

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: your approach is really nice.