# List of all possible permutations of factors of a number

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7

I am trying to find all the possible factorizations of a number provided in Python.

For example: 1)given **n=12**,
the output will be, **f(n)=[[2,2,3],[4,3],[6,2],[12]]**

2) given **n=24**,
the output will be,**f(n)=[2,2,2,3],[2,2,6],[2,12],[4,6],[8,3],[24]]**

Here is my code:

```
def p(a):
    k=1
    m=1
    n=[]
    for i in range (len(a)):
        for j in range(0,i+1):
            k*=a[j]
        for l in range(i+1,len(a)):
            m*=a[l]
        n+=[[k,m],]
        k=1
        m=1
    return n

def f(n):
    primfac = []
    d = 2
    while d*d <= n:
        while (n % d) == 0:
            primfac.append(d)  
            n //= d
        d += 1
    if n > 1:
        primfac.append(n)
    return p(primfac)
```

But my code returns following values:

1) For **n=12**,The output is ,

```
[[2, 10], [4, 5], [20, 1]]
```

2)1) For **n=24**,The output is ,

```
[[2, 12], [4, 6], [8, 3], [24, 1]]
```

What can I do for getting relevant results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know python, so can't help you with the code, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40693429/620908) in an explanation I provided for a related question (a bit of Java code as well, if you can read Java).

1. get your number factored with multiplicity - this is with high probability the most expensive step O(sqrt(N)) - you can stop here if this is al that you want
2. build you sets of {1, p<sub>i</sub><sup>1</sup>, p<sub>i</sub><sup>1</sup>, ..., p<sub>i</sub><sup>m<sub>i</sub></sup>} - p<sub>i</sub> being a prime factor with multiplicity of m<sub>i</sub>
3. perform a Cartesian product between these sets and you'll get all the divisors of your number - you'll spend longer time here only for numbers with many distinct factors (and multiplicities) - e.g 2<sup>10</sup> x 3 <sup>8</sup> x 5<sup>4</sup> x 7<sup>3</sup>  will have 1980 divisors.

Now, each divisor `d` resulted from the above will come with it's pair (`N/d`) so if you want distinct factorisation irrespective of the order, you''l need to sort them and eliminate the duplicates.